# Document viewer control?

Tags: document

We are creating a custom document management application that requires a viewer for the user to quickly move through various documents no matter the format (image files, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .ppt, .rtf, .pdf).  Is there a control out there that will handle this problem?  If not, what approach would you recommend we use?  We would rather not use any MS products (embedded Office viewers for example) due to licensing concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several, however, you need to license them all as well.

One of the most popular choices is the [Outside In SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/content-management/oit/viewer.html).

> Outside In Viewer Technology is a
>   software development kit (SDK) that
>   enables file viewing, printing, and
>   copy/paste functionality of nearly 500
>   file formats. It includes an
>   annotation API which allows the
>   developer to highlight, hide or insert
>   text in a document view without
>   altering the underlying native file.
>   Its use is appropriate to solutions
>   that can benefit from desktop viewing
>   functionality.

- Available on Windows, Unix and Linux platforms
- Access via a C API or ActiveX Control for Visual Basic or other ActiveX compliant development environments
- Includes sample applications with source code

Answer (score 1):

You should definitaly check out http://www.snowbound.com/products/document-viewer it supports support for all popular document types (including AFP, Word, PDF, PNG, PCL, TIFF) among many others, which covers the ones you were asking about and more.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [adeptol ajaxdocumentviewer](http://www.ajaxdocumentviewer.com). They have Online Document Viewing Available in the Cloud also and on premise option too. A very low cost option and let's you embed more than 300 file formats with no active x or applets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for HTML rendering,edit and annotations for the documents, you can give Docspad a try. http://www.docspad.com